# Clear corresponding input on unchecked box?

Tags: jquery, html

Looking for a way to alter this script so i can use it on multiple checkbox/inputs without having to right a separate function for each.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="child_div_1">MULTI SWITCH
<hr>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="apple-switch reveal" id="swm_box">
<span class="qntylabel">SWM 30</span>
<div class="part">
<input type="text" name="swm" id="swm" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" pattern="\d*" value="test1"/>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="apple-switch reveal" id="rc66_box">
<span class="qntylabel">RC 66</span>
<div class="part">
<input type="text" name="rc66" id="rc66" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" pattern="\d*" value="test2"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#swm_box").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(":checked")){ //checks if the checkbox/this is selected or not
            $("#swm").val(""); //empty the input value
        } else { } //nothing
    });
});
</script>
```

Currently works for first check/input to clear the value.

However it does not work for the second, due to it being id specific.

http://jsfiddle.net/qpg7ut0j/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't see you want jQuery. Anyway, here is a javascript-solution. Basically use `forEach` on an array containing the text-input-names. I'm sure jQuery can do this even shorter.

```js
["swm","rc66"].forEach(
  el=>document.querySelector("#"+el+"_box").onchange=e=>{
    if(e.target.checked) {
      document.querySelector("#"+el).value="";
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="swm_box"><br>
<input type="text" id="swm" value="test1"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="rc66_box"><br>
<input type="text" id="rc66" value="test2"/>
```

Comment: This works, just had to change it to `(!e.target.checked)`, since its for when its unchecked. i have 19 total checkboxes, so it sucks to have to list all the id's in the array, but this still is cleaner than my previous solution.

Answer (score 0):

For a jQuery solution, the main selector will need to be changed from an id to a class.  This will target all elements with the class specified. You will need to edit the if statement inside the function to figure out which text input should be changed.  I grabbed the id from the checkbox, removed the "_box" from the id and used that to change the value of the text input. The resulting script would look similar to this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".inputClass").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(":checked")){ //checks if the checkbox/this is selected or not
        var ourCheckedBox = $(this).attr('id'); //get our id from the checked element
        var ourInputToEdit = str.replace("_box", ""); //strip out "_box"
        $("#" + ourInputToEdit + "").val(""); //empty the input value
        } else { } //nothing
    });
});
</script>
```

The only change needed in the html would be to add a class of "inputClass" to all input elements you want to apply the .click function to.

```
<div class="child_div_1">MULTI SWITCH
  <hr>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="apple-switch reveal inputClass" id="swm_box">
    <span class="qntylabel">SWM 30</span>
    <div class="part">
      <input type="text" name="swm" id="swm" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" pattern="\d*" value="test1"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="apple-switch reveal inputClass" id="rc66_box">
    <span class="qntylabel">RC 66</span>
    <div class="part">
      <input type="text" name="rc66" id="rc66" class="qnty" placeholder="QTY" pattern="\d*" value="test2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```